# Attaching Database

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I am very new to Sequel Server. For Practice, I created a Database where I imported some sample datasets (mostly excel files) via SSIS. The database consists of 6 tables. I was wondering if there is a way I can send the database (I created) via email or share it by any other way. Like Adventureworks was available for download and also for attaching to SQL SERVER, is there a way I can do the same for my practice database?

Thank you,
Regards,

Sourav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can backup the database you created to a file and send it over to anyone. Right click on your database, Tasks -> Backup

Comment: One problem I am getting in trying to re-attach the file to see if the process works: The error says it is not a primary database file. Could you please throw some light?

Comment: With MSSQL databases you have two files the *.mdf (the data file) and *.ldf (the log file). Please refer to this article in order to backup and restore database:  https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a367/how-to-backup-and-restore-a-mssql-database.aspx

Comment: Thanks again. Say, I email the .bak file. Will the recipient be able to attach it to their sequel server? If I covert the backup file to .mdf or any other preferred format, my purpose would not be served then.

Comment: If you sent the .bak  file to someone else he will (in general) be able to attach the database to his SQl Server